# Wait for keyboard input inside a while-read loop

Tags: shell-script, read, user-input

I have a bash script with a construction like this:

```
while read foo bar baz;
do
    echo "Processing $foo $bar $baz"
    # more code here
done < /etc/somefile
```

Inside the loop, I would like the script to wait for keyboard input (basically just "press Enter to continue". However, the following code inside the loop

```
echo "Press [ENTER] to continue"
read -s
```

doesn’t cause the script to stop there—apparently it takes its input from the supplied file rather than the keyboard. How can I force it to read from the keyboard?

Answer (score 6):

Feeding a file into the loop will affect each `read` instance in the loop unless explicitly specified otherwise. The following worked:

```
echo "Press [ENTER] to continue"
read -s < /dev/tty
```

Answer (score 3):

The following `/bin/sh` code opens file descriptor 3 as a copy of standard input. Inside the loop, the `read keypress` reads from this new file descriptor, and not from the file fed into the loop itself. At the end, the file descriptor is explicitly closed.

```
exec 3<&0
while read -r foo bar baz; do
    printf 'Processing %s, %s and %s\n' "$foo" "$bar" "$baz"
    printf 'Press <enter> to continue: ' >&2
    read keypress <&3
done <file
exec 3<&-

echo 'Done.'
```

This allows you to use, e.g.,

```
yes | ./script.sh
```

to "automatically press <kbd>enter</kbd>" at every prompt.